# Expanding a notification from the notification bar

Tags: android

Is it possible to make a notification expand on click?  For example, by clicking on the notification it would bring up a listview with more options.

In the app I'm working on, a user has many files.  Each time the app is opened a notification is issued with the number of files that have been modified.  Is there any way to click on this notification so I can see a sub-list of each file?

I could do this by registering an intent with a ListActivity, but is there a cleaner way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'cleaner'? And why are you using `ListActivity`? `ListView` is a better idea, I think.

Comment: When the user clicked on the notification it would navigate to the ListActivity where the sublist would be shown.  I didn't know you could just have a ListView and no activity associated with it.

Comment: You could use a `Dialog` or even a `Toast` (although the toast won't last long enough to be useful).